# How to reduce time taken to insert 40000+ records in salesforce using trigger

Tags: trigger, collection

i am inserting 40000+ records one time in my organization. suppose as per my requirement 19543 record is satisfied to my condition. but 1 to 19542 records are cross checked(unsatisfied ) in my condition. so it will take time. how to reduce that time, how to find satisfied records with less time and 
how can i optimise the my code,
 here is my code :

```
    list<emp__c> agsdt= [select id,name,Email__c,empid__c from emp__c];         
   list<org__c> ordt= [select id,name, orgid__c from org__c where id=:Resid];  

     for(emp__C ags:agsdt){          
         for(org__c res:ordt){  
            if(ags.empid__c ==res.orgid__c){

                if(ags.Email__C !=null){                       

                   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                   mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owdId);
                   mail.setTargetObjectId(conid);
                   mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);                       
                   mail.setWhatId(Res.id);
                   mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                   mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {ags.Email__c}); 
                   mail.setBccSender(false);
                   mail.setUseSignature(false);
                   mail.setReplyTo('test@gmail.com');
                   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                   allmsg.add(mail);

                 }

                  if(ags.Email__C ==null){                     
                        ----

                    }
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between emp__c and org__c

Comment: no relationship @umithuckan

Comment: Then below(sfdcfox) is the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a map and populate it. Here's what that would look like:

```
Map<Id, Org__c[]> orgs = new Map<Id, Org__c[]>();
for(Org__c record: ordt) {
    if(orgs.containKey(record.orgid__c)) {
        orgs.get(record.orgid__c).add(record);
    } else {
        orgs.put(record.orgid__c, new Org__c[] { record });
    }
}
for(Emp__c ags: agsdt) {
    if(orgs.containsKey(record.Empid__c)) {
        for(Org__c res: orgs.get(record.Empid__c)) {
             // ags.EmpId__c does equal res.OrgId__c here
        }
    }
}
```

This method will allow you to iterate over Org__c records that are related to the current Emp__c record in the outer loop.